# How can I open a Terminal window directly from my current Finder location?

Tags: terminal, finder

I was wondering if there was any was I could right click inside any instance of a "Finder" window such that I have an option that says "Open Terminal Here". It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal provides Services for opening a new terminal window or tab at the selected folder in Finder. They also work with absolute pathnames selected in text (in any application). You can enable these services with **System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services**. Look for "New Terminal at Folder" and "New Terminal Tab at Folder". You can also assign them shortcut keys.

In addition, you can now drag folders (and pathnames) onto the Terminal application icon to open a new terminal window, or onto a tab bar in a terminal window to create a new tab in that window. If you drag onto a tab (rather than into the terminal view) it will execute a complete `cd` command to switch to that directory without any additional typing.

As of OS X Mountain Lion 10.8, Command-Dragging into a terminal will also execute a complete `cd` command.

Note: The New Terminal at Folder service will become active **when you select a folder in Finder**. You cannot simply have the folder open and run the service "in place". Go back to the parent folder, select the relevant folder, then activate the service via the Services menu or context menu.

Comment: T'was already enabled on mine, but with key set to 'none'. Is there a recommended shortcut? (side note: *really* wish MacOS had something set by default, so it wouldn't be left to everyone having to do it manually themselves and hence different shortcuts for each user)

Comment: @stevec or at least a list of available shortcuts. Btw: this is only working when you click on a folder, not when you don't have a folder or a file focused. In this case it should just open on the desktop or in root and be a global shortcut in general. Super annoying.

Comment: Doesn't work on Bug Sur. I couldn't find Services on the right-click menu!

Comment: @Dr.jacky it works in Big Sur. You clicked on a folder icon+name, not the window background? Did it work for you before upgrading to Big Sur or is this the first time you've tried using Services in Finder?

Comment: @ChrisPage Thanks! It works. The issue was, there were lots of items in right-click so, I couldn't see that specific one.

Comment: @Dr.jacky You can disable services you don’t use to reduce the number of menu items.

Comment: This only works when your are outside of a given folder, and you are selecting it. It does not work if you are already in it. Classic Apple.

Answer (score 25):

The solution to your troubles is called [**Go2Shell**](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/go2shell/id445770608?mt=12) and it does exactly what you're describing. You can find it on the App Store and best of all... it's totally free.

[image: Go2Shell]

Comment: Not work in Catalina!

Comment: The version on the App Store doesn't download for Catalina, but the version directly from the developers can be downloaded and appears to work: https://zipzapmac.com/Go2Shell

Comment: Didn't get it running on Catalina either. Even though I pressed "add to finder" button I do not see any new button in Finder.

Comment: Direct link: https://zipzapmac.com/DMGs/Go2Shell.dmg

Answer (score 23):

[cdto](https://github.com/jbtule/cdto#cd-to) seems like it is just what you need. It is a mini-application, designed to be put in the Finder's toolbar, when you run it it will open a terminal window and `cd` to the current directory in Finder.

Comment: Works well on Catalina

Comment: Works well on Big Sur.

Comment: Newer versions [don't support](https://github.com/jbtule/cdto/issues/46) opening iTerm2 :\

Comment: Works well in Ventura for M1/2 chips

Answer (score 19):

For those using iTerm, the AppleScript syntax has change in iTerm version 3. Here's the full procedure to follow to create a shortcut in the Finder.

1. Launch Automator.
2. Select "Application" :

[image: illustration of instructions]

3. Choose "run Applescript" :

[image]

4. Paste the code below:

   ```
   -- get the current directory in Finder
   on run {input, parameters}
       tell application "Finder"
           set _cwd to quoted form of (POSIX path of (folder of the front window as alias))
       end tell
       CD_to(_cwd)
   end run

   -- change directory in iTerm (version >= 3)
   on CD_to(_cwd)
       tell application "iTerm"
           activate

           try
               set _window to first window
           on error
               set _window to (create window with profile "Default")
           end try

           tell _window
               tell current session
                   write text "cd " & _cwd & ";clear;"
               end tell
           end tell
       end tell
   end CD_to
   ```

[image]

5. Click "File" -> "Export" to export as an `.app`, save it in `/Applications`.
6. Move the application to the Finder icons bar while holding <kbd>⌘</kbd> :

[image]

Done !

You can change the icon in the Finder by following the instructions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372/121400) (change the icon of the application you created with Automator).

Comment: Any update for big Sur ?

Comment: For iTerm, the [existing answer about Services](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20633/325877) also applies: Finder > Services > New iTerm2 Window Here is available by default.

Answer (score 15):

A different approach: [DTerm](http://decimus.net/DTerm), which gives you a floating command prompt at the top of the window. This works in many apps, not just Finder.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

If you have the "Path Bar" shown (View > Show Path Bar). You can Right Click on any element to get a Open In Terminal option

[image]

Comment: This is perhaps the best answer, no System property change, no additional tools.

Answer (score 11):

I mostly use this function:

```
cf() {
  cd "$(osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)')"
}
```

You could also assign a shortcut to a script like the ones below.

Reuse an existing tab or create a new window (Terminal):

```
tell application "Finder" to set p to POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)
tell application "Terminal"
    if (exists window 1) and not busy of window 1 then
        do script "cd " & quoted form of p in window 1
    else
        do script "cd " & quoted form of p
    end if
    activate
end tell
```

Reuse an existing tab or create a new tab (Terminal):

```
tell application "Finder" to set p to POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)
tell application "Terminal"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    activate
    if busy of window 1 then
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
    end if
    do script "cd " & quoted form of p in window 1
end tell
```

Always create a new tab (iTerm 2):

```
tell application "Finder" to set p to POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)
tell application "iTerm"
    if exists current terminal then
        current terminal
    else
        make new terminal
    end if
    tell (launch session "Default") of result to write text "cd " & quoted form of p
    activate
end tell
```

The first two scripts have a few advantages compared to the services added in 10.7:

- As of 10.9, there is a bug where services that receive folders as input are never listed in the services menu in column view. If you assign the New Terminal Tab at Folder service a keyboard shortcut, it doesn't work in column view.
- They use the folder on the title bar instead of requiring you to select a folder first.
- They reuse the frontmost tab if it is not busy, e.g. running a command, displaying a man page, or running emacs.

If you use 10.7 or 10.8, change `tell application "Finder" to set p to POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)` to:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists Finder window 1 then
        set p to POSIX path of (target of Finder window 1 as alias)
    else
        set p to POSIX path of (path to desktop)
    end if
end tell
```

There is a bug in 10.7 and 10.8 (but not in 10.9 or 10.6) where Finder ignores windows created after the last time focus was moved to another application and back when getting the `insertion location` property.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your scripts, but they don't seem to work properly on OS Catalina, can you help me with my issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399682/applescript-to-open-terminal-at-directory-does-not-work

Answer (score 6):

Try this:
https://github.com/nmadhok/OpenInTerminal

It works with the Finder's sidebar items, multiple folder/file selections and anything you could think of. Really easy to use!

Comment: It works well with high sierra!

Answer (score 5):

You can drag any file or folder from the finder onto a Terminal window to insert a string of said file or folder's absolute path.

This will work on any standard install (at least back until 10.4 Tiger [*¿maybe earlier?*]) without needing additional software our twiddling of preferences, either of which may later freak out your non-techy friend if it happens to be his/her Mac that you’re working on. This trick also works for any process that is running in the Terminal, e.g. emacs or vi (assuming you’ve got vi in the appropriate mode, or however it is that you people who use vi do).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the service feature.

The following site contains an example of such a service:
http://blog.leenarts.net/2009/09/03/open-service-here/

Answer (score 3):

## OpenInTerminal

You could try OpenInTerminal: https://github.com/Ji4n1ng/OpenInTerminal

It has a really nice icon and is implemented as Finder Extension. There are also two versions ('regular' and 'lite).

OpenInTerminal can also be installed using [homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
brew install --cask openinterminal
```

Answer (score 3):

Service Station, [on the Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/service-station/id1503136033), allows you to fully customize your right-click menu in Finder.

One of the most popular actions is to open Terminal by right-clicking in the Finder:

[image: Open Terminal from Finder using Service Station]

I'm the developer and would love if you gave it a try.

- https://servicestation.menu
- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/service-station/id1503136033

The app is fully sandboxed and uses the modern Finder Sync Extension API. I like using it more than the Services menu, as detailed in other answers, as you don't have to dig through the submenu.

Answer (score 2):

## ShellHere

http://etresoft.org/shellhere.html
— Etresoft and John Daniel

> … right click inside any instance of a "Finder" window …

I don't know whether it can be reached through a contextual menu, but I keep ShellHere [in the toolbar of Finder](http://www.wuala.com/grahamperrin/public/2011/07/31/c/001.png/?mode=list).

Answer (score 2):

## OnMyCommand

http://free.abracode.com/cmworkshop/on_my_command.html
— version 2.3 (2011-01-16)

Screenshot etc. at http://www.wuala.com/grahamperrin/public/2011/07/31/d/?mode=gallery

Installed and used by me on Snow Leopard before upgrading to Lion. Too soon for me to say whether version 2.3 is compatible with Lion.

Answer (score 2):

You can the app I developed [FinderGo](https://github.com/onmyway133/FinderGo), which is open source and easy to use

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use this for years http://openterminal.quentin.paris/
Just right click on anywhere Finder, choose Open Terminal

Comment: Best, works on latest macos 2022

Answer (score 0):

Try the app [Open Terminal](https://web.archive.org/web/20120521102946/http://homepage.mac.com/thomasw/OpenTerminal/)

> This application allows you to open a Terminal window with the path of the current Finder window.

[image: Open Terminal app icon]