# Jump to the Terminal's right directory from Finder's specific directory

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“open terminal here”?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/open-terminal-here)

If I browse my Apple Finder at

```
/Users/arie/Documents/shugyou/genjutsu/fp
```

How can I possibly go to **Terminal** with that very same directory? So that I won't need to do two less productive commands (1) open Terminal from Spotlight, and then (2) type `cd /Users/arie/Documents/shugyou/genjutsu/fp`.

I use Mac OS X 10.5.8. Note I don't (want to) use iTerm. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cdto](http://code.google.com/p/cdto/) - Finder Toolbar button to open a Terminal window

[cdff](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060719155640762) - Switch Terminal dir to frontmost window of certain apps

Comment: problem's solved, thanks! I use cdto as you recommended. I copied the app to my Finder's toolbar and it's working beautifully. IMO this app should come with Apple OS X default feature.

Answer (score 2):

You should give [that](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dterm/id415520058?mt=12) application a try. It works on 10.6 as well as on 10.5 ;-)

[Link to the website](http://decimus.net/DTerm)

Answer (score 1):

I use [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) and this AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder" to set il to insertion location as alias
set cmd to "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of il
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    try
        do script with command cmd in window 1
    on error
        do script with command cmd
    end try
end tell
```

---

[Lion](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html)
has services called *New Terminal at Folder* and *New Terminal Tab at Folder*:

> #### Built-in systemwide services for Terminal
>
> You can create new sessions based on Finder folders or text paths selected in any application.

Comment: Very interesting service indeed.