# Open Finder window from current Terminal location?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, path

If I am in a specific path in a Terminal window, how can I open that same window in a new Finder window?

Note: This is the opposite of [opening a Terminal from Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/open-terminal-here).

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Typing `open .` in Terminal will open the current working directory in a Finder window.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. I'd seen it before, but forgot it.

Comment: Looks like this is broken in 10.9 Mavericks. Any workaround?

Comment: @WolfgangFahl It still works for me in 10.9 Mavericks.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl Was your Mavericks install a fresh install or an upgrade?  My upgraded install of Mavericks lets me use this command.

Comment: of four Mavericks installs i did the problem only happend once for an upgrade install. All otheres were fine. The problem with the upgrade install also went away after a while. Strange ...

Comment: Also working on Yosemite 10.10.5 here.

Comment: Works on macOS High Sierra

Comment: Related: You can switch to the existing Finder window using `open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app`

Answer (score 10):

#### Stretch goal!

*To expand on the answer above (because the more appropriate [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101432/how-do-i-launch-finder-from-terminal-or-command-line) is marked as a dupe and can't receive new answers)...*

I've added a function to my ~/.bash_profile to handle revealing a file or directory:

```sh
# Reveal a file or directory in Finder
reveal() {
  # grab the first arg or default to pwd
  local basedir=${1:-${PWD}}

  if [[ -f "$basedir" ]]; then
    # ..we passed a file, so use its containing directory
    basedir=$(dirname "$basedir")
  fi
  # basedir is a directory in now, so open will activate Finder.
  # The argument is quoted to accommodate spaces in the filename.
  open "$basedir"
}
```

…one liner:

```sh
reveal() { local dir=${1:-${PWD}}; [[ -f "$dir" ]] && dir=$(dirname "$dir") || true; open "$dir"; }
```

To install the function:

- paste/save it into ~/.bash_profile
- `source ~/.bash_profile` or open a new terminal/tab

The context for my use is that I'll be browsing around using `ls` with tab completion, then when I find what I'm looking for, I can `reveal` (or `cd` or `subl`) the most recent arg, like:

```
ls dir/subdir<tab tab>
subsubdir  anotherdir
ls dir/subdir/anotherdir
reveal !$
```

*Thanks to @nohillside, @Ed Randall, and Community for improvements!*

Comment: worth noting that the only thing that this adds to `open .` is allowing us to pass a filename and get the containing directory :)

Comment: Good plan, I simplified and enhanced this slightly:  (1) named the function `finder`;  (2) first line inside the function `local basedir=${1:-${PWD}}`  (3) shortened the if/else to `if [[ -f ${basedir} ]] ; basedir=$(dirname ${basedir}) ; fi`

Comment: Tx @EdRandall! Maybe someone will come along and help me understand how to also allow piping to this function without waiting for input when stdin is empty ! cf https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33049/how-to-check-if-a-pipe-is-empty-and-run-a-command-on-the-data-if-it-isnt

Answer (score 7):

```
open .
```

As a nice addition, add an alias in .bash_profile or .bash_aliases if you have one.

```
alias finder='open'
```

Then you can use `finder .` which I think is more intuitive.

Answer (score 5):

If you have `autojump` installed, you don't even have to type the full path to the directory. You can simply type `jo partialdirectoryname`, and autojump will open a new Finder window in the specified directory.

I love this method, because you don't have to remember the entire directory name. Autojump keeps a list of most commonly used locations, and automatically knows which directory you're referring to, even if you only give it part of the name.

Comment: I do have autojump installed but I get `jo command not found`

Answer (score 3):

Typing `open .` in Terminal will open the current working directory in a Finder window.

But there is also an alternative version

```
open `pwd`
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid just `open` is not enough, for example, if you have a directory named `/Users/hanley/repo/iconnect/MobileDevice.xcframework`, you will get error after you use `open /Users/hanley/repo/iconnect/MobileDevice.xcframework`:

```
No application knows how to open URL file:///Users/hanley/repo/iconnect/MobileDevice.xcframework/ (Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "kLSApplicationNotFoundErr: E.g. no application claims the file" UserInfo={_LSLine=1608, _LSFunction=runEvaluator}).
```

So I advise we can use `` open -b com.apple.finder `pwd` ``  to open current directory in `Finder.app`.

For more convenience, you can alias it with `` alias ofd='open -b com.apple.finder `pwd`' ``, then `ofd` command will directly open current directory in Finder.app

For more usage of `open`, please read `man open`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old thread. At the terminal typing `open .` opens the current directory as others stated. In addition, the following will reveal (but not open) files/folder `open -R .` A combination of both becomes really powerful and time saver. You can also open all the Text files with `open *.txt` command in the current directory. How cool is that!