# How do I launch Finder from terminal or command line

Tags: macos, applications, command-line

I use command line a lot, like most programmers. 
I want to be able to launch Finder, Safari or any other application for that matter from command line e.g.

> finder .

where it will start Finder app, and the set the view to the current folder that I am in at the command line.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. I found this when Finder was force quitted and I wanted to launch it again. The other question doesn't address this aspect of the problem, this one does.

Comment: I agree: not a duplicate. This question is about how to launch the program. The other is just about how to open a new window.

Answer (score 677):

To open your current directory in `Finder` from `Terminal`, type `open .`

So, if you want Documents: `open Documents`

Library: `open /Library`

Downloads: `open Downloads`

And so on.

Comment: Boom! `open .` is the winner here.

Comment: you did fine - linking the dupes helps with search terms. Your answer or this questions' words get indexed so that people searching the internet find the right answer.

Comment: I've been wondering for some time what the Mac equivalent to "explorer ." was.  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work if your current directory is an application, like /Applications/Something.app.  It will open that app instead of finder.

Comment: Important note, which was helpful to me - if you've `Force Quit`ted the Finder and it doesn't relaunch and you happen to have a Terminal window open, you can relaunch the finder by simply opening a directory, like `open .` as indicated here.

Comment: @Segfault To force it to open an application as a file in Finder, rather than the open the application itself, use the `-R` option: "-R  Reveals the file(s) in the Finder instead of opening them." For example, you can do `cd /Applications/Preview.app; open -R .` and it will open Finder, not Preview.

Comment: `open \`pwd\`` is safer, does the same thing as `open .`

Comment: What if I want to open Finder and connect to a server? `open ftp://whatever` doesn't recognize the protocol, instead it tries to look for a file called `whatever` in a folder called `ftp:`.

Comment: Related: You can switch to the existing Finder window using `open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app`

Comment: If the window doesn't pop up, check the `Terminal` menu to see if `Secure Keyboard Entry` is checked. This makes Terminal stay in the foreground. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253635465 If you can't uncheck it, try a different terminal emulator.