# Open terminal window on a particular folder

Tags: macos, utilities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I open a Terminal window directly from my current Finder location?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/how-can-i-open-a-terminal-window-directly-from-my-current-finder-location)

On Windows there is a utility which opens the command prompt on a particular folder. Basically you right click a folder and select "open command prompt here" and it open the command prompt and puts user in that particular directory. Is there any utility similar to this on mac?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420456/open-terminal-here-in-mac-os-finder

Answer (score 0):

1. Open System Preferences > Keyboards > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Select Services > New Terminal at Folder

Done!