# How can I open a Terminal window directly from my current Terminal location?

Tags: macos, terminal, shortcut

Related to [How can I open a Terminal window directly from my current Finder location?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/how-can-i-open-a-terminal-window-directly-from-my-current-finder-location), I would like to have a terminal window open in one location, and open another one.

E.g. under Linux, I could be in ~/foo/bar/files/ in one terminal window, and type Ctrl-Shift-N and a new window would open at that same location.

In Mac OS X, I can only do ⌘N which opens a new terminal in my home directory. Is there any way to open the new terminal in the current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the Terminal settings Terminal -> Preferences -> Startup -> New windows open with: *Same Working Directory*.

[image]

Comment: Damn, looked right at it and didn't see it. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting … it only works if the terminal is at a shell prompt. Well, I can live with it.

Comment: OK, I think I figured that last issue out -- the shell writes the current PWD into the title bar, and I think terminal window is using that information to figure out where to place a new window. If an app has changed the title bar label (and I've programmed vim to do just that), then the terminal window app can't figure it out.