# Open Terminal via Finder (hitting F4?)

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, finder

On Linux file manager, I think Dolphin (not sure right now, sorry) I can open Konsole just hitting F4. I would like to have the same on MacOS/Finder, openning Terminal instead. Is it possible?

I'm on El Captain.

Comment: What version of OS X/macOS are you running?

Comment: How does an Automator service containing an Applescript , triggered from standard key commands sound? I'll add it as an answer if that will do you.

Comment: "Automator service containing an Applescript , triggered from standard key commands" seems interestingly. I would like to know more.

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/how-can-i-open-a-terminal-window-directly-from-my-current-finder-location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Go2Shell](http://zipzapmac.com/go2shell) for that purpose. It's a free app which can be added to Finder. Clicking on it will open a new Terminal window with the current directory.

You can get it on the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id445770608).

Answer (score 2):

Another great tool is [cdto](https://github.com/jbtule/cdto) by Jay Tuley.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a Service [a Service is just the best/simplest way to launch an app via key command, saves having to define plists etc]

If you *just* need to launch a default Terminal, very simply...

- Launch Automator [Applications/Utilities]
- Select New Service
- In the Actions list on the left, Select Automator, then Run Applescript from the 2nd column.
- Copy/paste `tell application "Terminal" to activate`
  *between the on run & end run commands.*
- Save [It will automatically save to the correct place for Services.
- Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services. Your new service will be right at the bottom of the list.
- Add a hot key

If you need to open Terminal *at your current location*, that already exists as a built-in Service, just find it in the list, activate & supply a key command.