# Unable to open a terminal window from specified folder with shortcuts

Tags: terminal

I am working on the latest MacOS.

By configuring `System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services`,
I attempt to open a terminal window directly from folder with shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+Cmd+T` following the answer [How can I open a Terminal window directly from my current Finder location? - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/how-can-i-open-a-terminal-window-directly-from-my-current-finder-location).

However, it failed to work.

[image]

What the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click on a folder first so it is highlighted, then use your keyboard shortcut for "New Terminal at Folder". It will open terminal at that folder's location.

Comment: Yes, I click and select a folder, did not work.

Comment: Just to be sure, you don't want to actually open the folder, just select it. I just created the same shortcut name, selected a folder on my Desktop, used the keyboard shortcut, and it worked. What OS are you using?

Comment: I have same the problem. I clicked one time and I tried to use the shortcut but it didn't work. My OS version is 11.2.3

Comment: @Furkanozturk Do you see the "New Terminal at Folder" or "New Terminal Tab at Folder" options when you control-click a folder? If not, then you need to make sure one or both those options are checked in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services. Also, double-check the shortcut key combination. It's worth noting that this will not work with folders listed in the finder window sidebar (i.e. the folders listed under Favorites, iCloud, Locations, etc.)

Comment: @Paul Brady Yes, I see the "New Terminal at Folder" and "New Terminal Tab at Folder" options. I set it on keyboard shortcuts and then I tried to use shortcuts but it didn't work after selected a folder. I open it through right-click anymore. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it didn't work after saving it multiple times. Then tried restarting my system. Ideally, it should work instantly. But try restarting once, it may help.