# How to delete .app from High Sierra OS?

Tags: terminal, finder, applications

I want to have **Open Terminal Here** context menu option in Finder.

I found this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/278915/176856 and have  installed the `.app` it suggests http://openterminal.quentin.paris/

It adds context menu option but it doesn't open usual terminal.

I want to delete this `.app` completely. How can I do it on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

The .app itself can be deleted like any other file using for example Finder or Terminal.app (use "rm -r" to delete the .app as it will be treated like a folder).