# How to open iterm from Finder?

Tags: finder, iterm

Imagine I'm in `/Users/beauthi/Documents` in Finder. I want to launch commands in my default terminal, which is iterm, in that location. Is there a specific trick in the Finder app to launch iterm and get directly to the directory `/Users/beauthi/Documents` ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you edit to explain what launch iTerm in a folder means?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/how-can-i-open-a-terminal-window-directly-from-my-current-finder-location

Comment: Glad it helped :) Somewhere on your view of the question should be a button or checkbox to say 'yes it helped' [no-one else can see it so I'm not sure exactly what it says] which will then close this as a duplicate of the other. This is not any kind of 'punishment' but it links the two together permanently so more people will find it when googling in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be using an app like "Open In Terminal" (free/open source).
https://github.com/Ji4n1ng/OpenInTerminal

This app adds a menu to the Finder toolbar which opens the current directory in your default terminal app or your preferred text editor. Most terminal apps and text editors are supported, including iTerm.

There are also a "lite" versions for either opening the directory in the terminal app or in the text editor with a single button.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to do it @Gummibando