# How can I launch a Virtualbox VM from the Dock?

Tags: macos, dock, virtualbox

How can I put my VirtualBox on my Dock in Mac OS X Lion.  I want to have it on my dock so I can click on it to launch it.

Answer (score 12):

I don't use Virtualbox, but based on a [couple](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) [resources](http://kindlevsmac.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/how-to-start-vbox-vm-using-scripts-command-lines/), it looks like you can launch a specific VM from the command line, which means we can create a basic Automator application to serve as a launcher, which you can then put in the Dock.

In **Automator**, create a new workflow. Add a **Run Shell Script** action, and enter `/abolute/path/to/vboxmanage startvm "vmname"` in the text box. Replace `vmname` with the name of your VM as it appears in the Virtualbox GUI (make sure to keep the quotes though). Save the workflow, setting the **File Format** to **Application**. Then drag the resulting app onto your Dock.

Comment: i did not work :(

Comment: Try running the `vboxmanage` command in Terminal and see what output it generates.

Comment: When I create the workflow, this is what my command looks like.  /usr/bin/vboxmanage startvm /Users/mark/VirtualBox\ VMs/Windows7\ Pro\ 64/Windows7\ Pro\ 64.vbox  -- I saved it as "Windows7"

Comment: Once I did that, I saved it to my /Applications folder and then copied the VirtualBox icon (`cmd-c, cmd-v` over the icon in the `cmd-i` (get info) for the Automator script) and dragged it to the Dock.

Comment: The parameter to the `startvm` command should be the *name* of the VM, not the path to its file.

Comment: @robmathers it seems to work better, at least for me using the full path to the vm.

Comment: Hmm okay, must be undocumented. In any event, is it working for you as an Automator application @MarkCohen?

Comment: Yup! It sure is.

Comment: i dont have have vboxmange?  I have /usr/bin/vboxwebsrv

Comment: Try replacing that path with `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage`, per [this forum post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&amp;t=18054).

Comment: this worked but how can I change the icon.

Comment: The easiest way to change the icon is to **Get Info** (File menu, or ⌘I) on the app you created, do the same on another file/app with the icon you want, select the icon and copy/paste it over.

Comment: i did not work.. I want to it and did a  ⌘I and then draged the new image i wanted on it but all that it did was start my vm

Comment: You can't drag and drop with app icons. Follow the instructions in [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/369/can-i-change-the-application-icon-of-an-automator-script).

Comment: It worked, but fails to do the only thing I wanted: to open the VM in the current workspace, not switch to the one where VirtualBox is already running (a different VM). :(

Comment: this solution works for adding any unix or brew utility to the dock, e.g. wxmaxima

Answer (score 3):

Right click VM in Manager, create desktop icon.  Select the desktop icon and press Control+Shift+Command+T

That's it done

Comment: Does not work: "Trying to open a VM config '/Users/BLAH/VMPATH/VMNAME.vbox' which has the same UUID as an existing virtual machine."