# True Full Screen in Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox

In OSX, how do I have a true full screen? When I go to full screen mode, the tab and navigation bar are still showing. Those toolbars are annoying when I try to watch a movie, etc.

This is the shot of the top of the screen:[image]

EDIT: I realized this may apply to other browsers such as Safari

Comment: Chrome has a presentation mode.

Comment: Most website movie players have a full-screen button (usually two arrows pointing to opposite corners of the screen) that enlarges the movie to fill the screen completely. Use that instead of the green Zoom button in the upper-left corner of the window.

Answer (score 24):

I'm on MacOS, January 2022.  To accomplish what we want:

1. Go to Firefox "full screen" mode as normal (e.g. Ctrl-Cmd-F)
2. On upper right of the screen is the "hamburger menu" (three horizontal lines); right-click it, then select "Hide Toolbars".

No Firefox extension needed.

[image: right-click the hamburger, hide toolbars]

Comment: This worked like a charm

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: This should 100% be the accepted answer! Worked great!

Comment: I had to control-click / right-click on an empty area outside of the of the address bar to get a similar context menu so the menus must have moved, that option is not in the “hamburger menu” anymore.

Answer (score 18):

On the about:config page search for the following key

**full-screen-api.allow-trusted-requests-only**

and set it to **false**

Then you can create a bookmark '*link*' with the following '*location*':

`javascript:document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()`

Edit: new FF supports shorter syntax, thanks @trss for suggestion

Comment: My mind is blown good sir. Haven't seen this functionality in Firefox since ~2013, thank you!

Comment: Remember that bookmarks can have a `keyword`, which allows you to activate this by going to the address bar and typing the keyword you've specified.

Comment: I was just looking for a one time solution and this pointed me in the right direction. Went with opening the console and adding the script to a click handler. BTW, `document.documentElement` is short (and clean) for `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]`.

Comment: This is the only thing that's remotely worked in my system including several add-ons and dropping a css file in the firefox profile. +1

Answer (score 6):

On `about:config`, set `browser.fullscreen.autohide` to `true` [1](https://support.mozilla.org/pt-BR/questions/1254683).

Bonus: also set `ui.prefersReducedMotion` to `1` and you'll have a slightly faster animation on macOS (or a hugely faster animation on Windows or Linux).

Comment: Thank you! Worked on Firefox version 105.0.3 (64-bit), on MacOS Monterey v 12.5.1.

Comment: If you don't find `ui.prefersReducedMotion` in your `about:config`, just create it. Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

### 2022 update

This answer is no longer correct due to native integration of this feature into Firefox. Look to other answers for better options.

### Original answer

By default there's no way to do this in native Firefox, but there is an extension called [Toolbar Autohide](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/fullscreen-toolbar-hover/) that should do exactly that! It allows you to use your mouse to make it appear again by hovering at the top of the screen where the toolbar would normally be.

Simply install the extension at that link and restart Firefox when it prompts you to do so. After Firefox restarts, right-click the toolbar and select `Maximized Autohide`; you should then be ready to go!

I would recommend changing an option for the add-on in the add-on manager (`command + shift + a`), though: under `General`, change `Transition Type` to `Slide-in` to make it a little prettier.

Lastly, keep in mind that hovering your mouse at the top of the screen can make the OS X bar appear as well, which can be mildly annoying (which would happen for almost any extension that does this type of thing). To get around this, make good use of key commands!

- `command + l` brings up the address bar so you can immediately start typing in a new URL
- `command + k` brings up the Firefox menu so you can select your print options, preferences, etc.
- `command + t` creates a new tab and focuses on it
- `control + tab` and `control + shift + tab` allows you to cycle through tabs just like `command + tab` and `command + shift + tab` allows you to cycle through windows in OS X

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that the recommended extension is not verified for use in Firefox Developer Edition, but works nonetheless.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the author has removed the extension from the link you've provided.

Comment: Replacement which works as of Jan 2017: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fullscreen-plus/

Comment: @zwol unfortunately that addon completely removes all toolbars when in full screen mode. This is not recommended, because all tools now are not available. Also, security may be compromised, because the address bar (which shows some security info, e.g. https and certificates) is permanently hidden unless full screen is exited. I'm still looking for an addon that does what it should in true full screen.

Comment: As of the latest Firefox version, the extension no longer works.

Comment: Downvoted because "there's no way to do this in native Firefox" is not true. See this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/435191/120350

Comment: @Zoltán no need to downvote. Notice the year of the question and answer — 7 years ago, this answer was correct ;) That said, I’ve updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by using Automator to create an Application that makes use of an `Action > Utilities > Run Shell Script`:

```
open -a Firefox
sleep 1
lsappinfo setinfo -app Firefox ApplicationType=UIElement
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Firefox" to set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of first window to true'
sleep 0.5
for f in "$@"; do open -a Firefox "$f"; done
```

I set the shell script `Shell:` to `/bin/sh` and `Pass input:` to `as arguments`, save it as "Firefox Full Screen" in `/Applications`, change its icon [as explained here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372/24974) and add it as an exception in `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy Tab > Accessibility`.

I then can click the application icon or run any of the following and it works:

- `open -a "Firefox Full Screen"`
- `open -a "Firefox Full Screen" --args "https://google.com"`
- `open -a "Firefox Full Screen" --args "https://google.com" "https://twitter.com"`

I'm using this coupled with the following `userChrome.css` to both evade a [well known issue with the macOS menu bar on full screen applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/make-the-menu-bar-never-show-while-in-full-screen) and [another long standing address bar and tab auto-hide bug that Firefox have with macOS native full screen](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740148).

**userChrome.css**

```
#navigator-toolbox[inFullscreen] {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 3px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navigator-toolbox[inFullscreen]:hover {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: show;
}

#content-deck[inFullscreen]{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

For a generic approach, [check my other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313628/24974).

**TIP**

- Firefox, by default, does not have any issue on Linux or Windows to auto-hide address bar and tabs in full screen as expected. With that said, I grabbed this `userChrome.css` from my ArchLinux setup. I use it on i3 and sway tiling window managers, with all the `[inFullscreen]` removed, to get address bar and tabs to auto-hide in **normal** bordless windows.

Comment: This css worked! I did have to set the `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` preference to True in about:config. Full instructions for userChrome.css [here](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by using JavaScript. For Firefox, execute this code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].mozRequestFullScreen()
```

On Safari, put this in a button `href` attribute:

```
javascript:if(!document.webkitFullscreenElement){document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].webkitRequestFullscreen();} else{document.webkitExitFullscreen()}
```

Obviously, this isn't very graceful unless in an extension or bookmarklet.

Comment: `TypeError: document.getElementByTagName is not a function`

needs to be Elements (note the s), in Firefox 43 on OS X anyway

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this that is handier than a bookmarklet and does not require fiddling with userChrome.css is to install Tampermonkey, then create an user-script with these contents:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fullscreen
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Add fullscreen to every website!
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*
// @icon         data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => { if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == "F") {
        let button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerHTML = "Switch to full screen";
        button.style.position = "fixed"
        button.style['z-index'] = "9999";
        button.style.left = "50%";
        button.style.top = "50%";
        button.style.width = "50%";
        button.style.height = "50%";
        button.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)"
        button.style.background = "yellow";
        button.style.color = "black";
        button.style.border = "solid 10px green";
        button.onclick = (e) => {
            document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
            button.remove()
        };
        document.documentElement.appendChild(button)
    }}, true);
})();
```

Then, Control+Shift+F will display a big button that you can click to make any page fullscreen.

The "button" step is needed because otherwise Firefox will refuse to switch to fullscreen as it believes the fullscreen request was not triggered by an user's action.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to get this working on FF Developer Edition v80 was the combination of:

1. Installing the plugin @Paul mentioned: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fullscreen_plus/
2. Setting `full-screen-api.allow-trusted-requests-only: false` in `about:config`

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox add-on recommended by pat-s
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fullscreen-any-site/
doesn't work for me as of this date--it doesn't do anything.

I found a workaround to get a full screen with no search bar and related stuff at the top, suitable for those websites that don't have a full-screen button. Click the PIP button on the right side of the screen, and then double click the PIP screen, and it will make it a full screen without any search bar or bookmark toolbar. It has its own stop and start button, but it is not suitable for websites that have their own full screen button because, although it works for that, you lose the native controls of the websites full screen. To get out of it, click the X in the upper left corner and then click the PIP button on the right of the screen and you will be back to the original screen.

Answer (score 0):

The extension Fullscreen Plus (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fullscreen_plus/) worked for me, for making full-screen of any website (note extensions do NOT function on mozilla extension web site, so you have to go to a different page).  CTRL-SHIFT-F full screens the current web site, including making the URL bar, tabs bar, and menu bar go away.

I did set full-screen-api.allow-trusted-requests-only to false and full-screen-api.macos-native-full-screen to true.  I don't think either of those were required.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this addon currently works: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fullscreen-any-site/

Currently fixed to `command + shift + o` but maybe custom hotkeys are supported in future versions.