# AppleScript saved as application doesn't execute whole script when argument is passed

Tags: applescript, command-line, high-sierra

I save the following AppleScript as application, to open Firefox in full screen and without the menu bar:

```
tell application "Firefox" to activate
delay 0.8
do shell script "lsappinfo setinfo -app Firefox ApplicationType=UIElement"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Firefox" to set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of last window to true
```

And execute it as:

```
open -a "Firefox Full Screen"
```

This works as expected, Firefox is opened, goes full screen, without the menu bar. The problem is when I try to call open with a URL:

```
open -a "Firefox Full Screen" "https://google.com"
```

This still opens Firefox, with the given URL in a new tab, but it doesn't execute the lines after `delay 0.8`, so it doesn't open in full screen. I don't understand why this happens and how to fix it.

I know those lines are not executed because the system doesn't warn that I need to add the application as an accessibility exception (when I don't have one added/enabled). It always warns if I don't pass the URL (and don't have an exception added/enabled).

### EDIT 1

I also tried to execute the following version with `open -a "Firefox Full Screen"`, `open -a "Firefox Full Screen" "https://google.com"`, `open -a "Firefox Full Screen" --args "https://google.com"` and it's worse given that it doesn't execute the last lines in any case:

```
on run argv
    tell application "Firefox"
        activate
        repeat with arg in argv
            open location (arg as text)
        end repeat
    end tell
    delay 0.8
    do shell script "lsappinfo setinfo -app Firefox ApplicationType=UIElement"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Firefox" to set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of last window to true
end run
```

### EDIT 2

It seems the problem is related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419700.

Comment: Leaving this as a comment rather than an answer because I can't test this right now.  However, my feeling is that you *might* resolve the problem by enclosing your code in an `on run argv...end run` handler. That way, the  URL(s) will pass to the AppleScript in the `argv` array, and you can use a `repeat with arg in argv` loop to `open location (arg as text)` in order to open the tabs that way after (hopefully) the rest of the script has excuted.

Comment: @CJK, I've tried that, but without a loop, just `on run argv \n tell application "Firefox" \n activate \n if (count of argv) > 0 then open item 1 of argv \n end tell \n end run`. It didn't work.

Comment: Read the man page for the `open` _comand_: "**--args** All remaining arguments are passed to the opened application in the argv parameter to main(). These arguments are not opened or interpreted by the **open** tool." So it should be `open -a "Firefox Full Screen" --args "https://google.com"` - Also do as suggested by CJK in his comment.

Comment: @user3439894 Also tried that, didn't work.

Comment: For what's worth, I tried a lot of combinations before asking. With and without `--args`, using `on run argv`, etc.

Comment: @pepper_chico `open item 1 of argv` is the wrong command if you’re running recent versions of *Firefox* and MacOS.  Use `open location`.

Comment: You should have included all of that in your question!

Comment: @CJK I tried that, both `open` and `open location`, both `open location item 1 of argv` and `open location (item 1 of argv)`

Comment: @CJK question edited with last attempt.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like passing arguments to an AppleScript saved as an application [has become broken at some point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419700). I accomplished my task by using Automator to create an equivalent new Application that makes use of an `Action > Utilities > Run Shell Script`:

```
open -a Firefox
sleep 1
lsappinfo setinfo -app Firefox ApplicationType=UIElement
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Firefox" to set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of first window to true'
sleep 0.5
for f in "$@"; do open -a Firefox "$f"; done
```

I set the shell script `Shell:` to `/bin/sh` and `Pass input:` to `as arguments`, save it as "Firefox Full Screen" in `/Applications`, change its icon [as explained here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372/24974) and add it as an exception in `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy Tab > Accessibility`.

I then can run any of the following and it works as expected:

- `open -a "Firefox Full Screen"`
- `open -a "Firefox Full Screen" --args "https://google.com"`
- `open -a "Firefox Full Screen" --args "https://google.com" "https://twitter.com"`

I'm using this coupled with the following `userChrome.css` to both evade a [well known issue with the macOS menu bar on full screen applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70985/make-the-menu-bar-never-show-while-in-full-screen) and [another long standing address bar and tab auto-hide bug that Firefox have with macOS native full screen](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740148).

**userChrome.css**

```
#navigator-toolbox[inFullscreen] {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 3px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navigator-toolbox[inFullscreen]:hover {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: show;
}

#content-deck[inFullscreen]{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

For a generic approach, [check my other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313628/24974).

**TIP**

- Firefox, by default, does not have any issue on Linux or Windows to auto-hide address bar and tabs in full screen as expected. With that said, I grabbed this `userChrome.css` from my ArchLinux setup. I use it on i3 and sway tiling window managers, with all the `[inFullscreen]` removed, to get address bar and tabs to auto-hide in **normal** bordless windows.

Comment: If you've answered your own question you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I'm just not doing it because, while it's a useful _solution to the problem_, I don't consider it an _actual answer_ to the question. If someone knows how to pass arguments using AppleScript rather than shell script or that it's in fact impossible and why, I'd accept it.

Comment: if I have time over the weekend I'll look at it and see if I can find a solution.